# how to add elements at Drawer Header - react-native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I am new to react native, I am trying to insert elements into the drawer header, my idea is to remove the title from the screen and create a new title with onPress and add two more elements, but I can't find the properties for this. thanks for reading me.

**my code**

```
<Drawer.Navigator
            drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#6A994E' },
                headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                drawerLabelStyle: { marginLeft: -25, fontSize: 15 },
                drawerActiveBackgroundColor: '#6A994E',
                drawerActiveTintColor: '#fff',
                headerRight: (props) => { <HeaderComponent {...props} /> }
            }}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name='Sales' component={SalesScreen} options={{ drawerIcon: SalesIcon}} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Inventory' component={InventoryScreen} options={{ drawerIcon: InventoryIcon }} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

**mockup**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the current title using `headerTitle` and other elements using `headerRight`. Something like this:

```js
screenOptions={{
...
  headerTitle: (props) => (
    <Pressable onPress={...}>
      <Text>New title</Text>
    </Pressable>
  ),
  headerRight: (props) => {
    return <HeaderComponent {...props} />;
  },
}}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have another question: Is there a way to style the prestable hover?

Comment: Yes, there is onHowerIn/Out callbacks: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onhoverin.